# Visual Studio 2010 and Office 2003 PIA: is that possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, office-2007, office-2010, office-2003, office-pia

I'm about to start porting a bunch of .NET apps to Visual Studio 2010 as some .NET 4 features are required in the apps. The resulting apps need to be able to call Office 2003, Office 2007 and Office 2010 interop assemblies.

What is a good way to setup a develop environment that supports this?